# socket.io is not connecting

Tags: html, node.js, sockets, socket.io

## Socket.IO version - `4.4.1`

### Server

```js
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const http = require("http");
const server = http.createServer(app);
const { Server } = require("socket.io");
const cors = require("cors");

const io = new Server(server, {
  cors,
});

const PORT = 3000;

app.use(cors());

io.on("connection", (socket) => {
  console.log("A user connected :)");
  socket.on("msg", console.log);

  socket.on("connect_error", (err) => {
    console.log(`connect_error due to ${err.message}`);
  });
});

server.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log("listening on *:" + PORT);
});
```

### HTML

> Inside body

```html
 <script
      src="https://cdn.socket.io/4.4.1/socket.io.min.js"
    ></script>
    <script>
      // socket.io
      console.log("Connecting..")
      const socket = io("http://localhost:3000")
      socket.on("connect", () => {
        console.log(socket.connected); // true
      });
    </script>
```

There is no error on either client or server, but still i am not able to connect to the server.

Comment: Try adding `socket.on('error', e => console.log(e));` and `io.on('error', e => console.log(e));` to the client.

Comment: To get lots of debug info from the socket.io client, add this to your browser Javascript before you try to make the socketio connection: `localStorage.debug = '*'`. See [Socket.io Logging and Debugging](https://socket.io/docs/v3/logging-and-debugging/) for more info.

Comment: Non of the above solution is working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you change this:

```
const io = new Server(server, {
   cors,
});
```

to this:

```
const io = new Server(server);
```

Then, your code starts working for me.  So, something is wrong with how you're trying to use cors with socket.io.  FYI, if you change the client to always use a webSocket as the transport, then you won't need CORS for your socket.io connection because a websocket connection is not subject to same origin restrictions.

```
const socket = io("http://localhost:3000", {transports: ["websocket"]});
```

By default a socket.io connection starts with http polling (which is subject to same origin restrictions) and then switching to a websocket after a few http requests.